# Get username using Lightning Data Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, data-service

Is there a way to get current running user name(email, id, whatever) using only data service?

Comment: ie without a server side controller ? i tried to just load user record using force:recorddata and i got an error "Entitiy not supported", I would say it is not possible to get user info without using a server side controller but would wait and see what others have to say.

Comment: Just one more thing about specifying what object to retrieve - it's not documented, but AFAIK it infers the object type by record ID provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible now.

```
<aura:attribute name="currentUser" type="User" />
<force:recordData
    fields="Name, Email, UserType"
    recordId="{!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}"
    targetFields="{!v.currentUser}"
    mode="VIEW"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not for now. You can find the list of supported entities in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm). I would expect the list to grow release after release, so keep an eye on it.